# Convert to lambda

Tags: c#, lambda

How do I convert the following to a Lambda?

```
Func<int, string> calcState = delegate(int test) 
    { 
        return (!MyList.All(i => i > test) ? 
            (MyList.Any(i => i > test) ? "ein Paar" : "Keiner") : "alle"); 
    };
```

Comment: As an added note, an unnamed delegate is in the technical sense a lambda (An anonymous function). C# names the ones that use Expression syntax Lambda, but that really is only a C# thing. Your question is not wrong; I'm saying this to add extra information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove `delegate` and `return` keywords. Also you don't need to specify type of parameter - it will be inferred:

```
Func<int, string> calcState = 
   test => (!MyList.All(i => i > test) ? (MyList.Any(i => i > test) ? "ein Paar" : "Keiner") : "alle");
```

Further reading: [Expression Lambdas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx)

Comment: Apparently there is an anti-lambda movement somewhere out there :)

Answer (score 1):

Do the following:

```
Func<int, string> calcState = test => (!MyList.All(i => i > test) ? (MyList.Any(i => i > test) ? "ein Paar" : "Keiner") : "alle");
```

That's it.

Answer (score 1):

It partially is already one, but thats what I would come up with:

```
Func<int, string> calcState = 
    test => (!MyList.All(i => i > test) ? 
    (MyList.Any(i => i > test) ? "ein Paar" : "Keiner") : "alle");
```

A Lambda is defined by the `=>`, so the `i => i > test` are already [Lambda-Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx).

P.S.: I hope this was just an example and in your real application you are pulling the strings from the resources (or similiar) and do not use hard-coded strings?